# If / Else in Powershell not behaving as expected?

Tags: powershell

Can someone explain to me why below is not working as expected?  In the below example, I would expect the `$shortFQDN` variable to be set as `test.com`, but I'm getting back `www.test.com`:

```bsh
$fqdn = 'dev.www.test.com'
$d3 = $fqdn.Split('.')[-3] #www
$d2 = $fqdn.Split('.')[-2] #website
$d1 = $fqdn.Split('.')[-1] #com

#Check if this is a 2LD domain (.com.au, .co.uk, .co.jp, etc.)
if ($d1 -ne 'com' -or 'net' -or 'org' -or 'edu' -or 'gov' -or 'biz') {
    $shortFQDN = -join ("$d3",'.',"$d2",'.',"$d1")
} else {
    $shortFQDN = -join ("$d2",'.',"$d1")
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  It seems like the if/else is not processing correctly...

Comment: That is not how If-Then syntax works. Each clause must be a complete comparison.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `if()` is wrong. Although you can say in English "if a is not b or c or d, then...", in virtually all programming languages - and scripting languages - you need to say "if a is not b and a is not c and a is not d, then...".

Rather than redoing the `$fqdn.Split()` three times and subscripting the result each time, just take the output from the first time, and assign it to a variable, then simply subscript the variable.

Also, PowerShell allows you to use ranges, much like some dialects of Pascal, and you can use the `-match` operator with regular expressions. I'd rewrite your code as

```
$fqdn = 'dev.www.test.com'
$d = $fqdn.Split(".")    # or $d = $fqdn -split "\."
$tlds = "com|net|org|edu|gov|biz"
if ( -not ($d[-3] -match $tlds) ) {
    $shortfqdn = $d[-3..-1] -join "."
} else {
    $shortfqdn = $d[-2..-1] -join "."
}
```

Comment: A further refinement could be to replace `-not ($d[-3] -match $tlds)` with `$d[-3] -notmatch $tlds`; I always forget which operators have `not`equivalents.

Comment: Thank you.  I had no idea about ranges.  How does a range differ from an array if you don't mind?

Comment: @DominicBrunetti - A range isn't a contrast for an array; it's a shorthand for subscripting, or sometimes it's called "slicing". The notation `a..b`, where `a` and `b` are of the same ordered type, generates an array of value starting with `a` and ending with `b`. If you use that as a subscript to an array, it 'slices' the array, returning an array of the specifically referenced elements.

Answer (score 7):

This chain of expressions:

```
$d1 -ne 'com' -or 'net' -or 'org' -or 'edu' -or 'gov' -or 'biz'
```

will translate to:

```
$d1 -ne 'com' -or $true -or $true -or $true -or $true -or $true
```

use the `-notcontains` operator instead:

```
if(@('com','net','org','edu','gov','biz') -notcontains $d1){
    ...
}
```

---

It's probably worth noting that your approach seems a bit fragile. It won't work for ccTLD's for which 2LD names are directly assigned - `www.test.de` will still return `www.test.de`

Comment: And with the current proliferation of non-ccTLDs, anyway, the entire approach is of questionable validity.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin absolutely!

Comment: I'm curious what the end goal is. Possibly an X-Y problem.

Comment: Yes - this is not a be-all-end-all script.  it will serve a very small set of conditions, all of which are defined above.  Certainly not valid for an "in the wild" use!  :)

Comment: @DominicBrunetti assuming your problem got solved you should accecpt JeffZeitlin's answer rather than mine, it's much more interesting :-)

Answer (score 3):

Syntactically, it looks like you're trying to do this:

```
if (($d1 -ne 'com') -or ($d1 -ne 'net') -or ($d1 -ne 'org') -or ($d1 -ne 'edu') -or ($d1 -ne 'gov') -or ($d1 -ne 'biz') {
    $shortFQDN = -join ("$d3",'.',"$d2",'.',"$d1")
} else {
    $shortFQDN = -join ("$d2",'.',"$d1")
}
```

However, it sounds like you actually want this logic:

```
if (($d1 -ne 'com') -and ($d1 -ne 'net') -and ($d1 -ne 'org') -and ($d1 -ne 'edu') -and ($d1 -ne 'gov') -and ($d1 -ne 'biz') {
    $shortFQDN = $d3,$d2,$d1 -join "."
} else {
    $shortFQDN = $d2,$d2 -join "."
}
```

A simplification is to use the `-notin`, which will check that the value is not contained in an array:

```
if ($d1 -notin @('com','net','org','edu','gov','biz') {
    $shortFQDN = $d3,$d2,$d1 -join "."
} else {
    $shortFQDN = $d2,$d1 -join "."
}
```

Note that `$d1` is 'com' in your example, so `www.test.com` is the expected value of `$shortFQDN`

<sub>thanks to [briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist) for `-join` part simplification</sub>

Comment: Just curious, why would you include dots manually in the array to be joined instead of just using dot as the delimiter of the join?

Comment: @briantist I can't see a good reason! Copied OP's post originally - now improved via editing, thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even notice it in the OP so that's on me (it was completely obvious); but the update is still welcome!